# What easy exercises can I add to my routine?

Tags: home-exercise

I'd like to think I workout every day but in reality I might workout every other day, on a good week.

Right now my routine consists of around 3 sets of between 15 and 20 push ups, around 30 reps with two 10 pound dumbbells and around 20 to 25 crunches.

It's definitely not what I would describe as an intense workout by a long shot but I'm just wondering what other easy things I can throw into my routine that could help?

Thanks.

Edit: I don't necessarily have any specific goals other than to be "in shape" I'm not too out of shape, I weigh around 140 lbs and I'm able to run on a treadmill for about a half hour without dying.

Comment: What are your reasons for working out?  What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What Tracy said. Also what does 'reps with two (...) dumbbells' mean? Curls, Extensions, Shoulder Press?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the terminology but i have two 10 pound "weights" I guess, I have one in each hand and I lift then together and lower them multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current exercises are all quite 'isolational'

I would suggest doing [bodyweight squats](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/BWSquat.html) which work all of your big leg and ass muscles.
When they get easy you can start holding your dumbbells in a '[goblet squat](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/grab-sit-repeat-the-simple-power-of-the-goblet-squat.html)' style to increase the load. Eventually you may even consider a barbell and weights.

Alongside that something like [burpees](http://www.exrx.net/Aerobic/Exercises/Burpee.html) will get you sweating, and can be made [harder](http://www.exrx.net/Aerobic/Exercises/BurpeeAdvanced.html) when they become too easy.

Answer (score 1):

As Tracy stated, your choice of exercises depends on the goals you hope to achieve. It also depends on your current fitness level when compared to your genetic potential. In other words, if you want your body to change, you have to continue to increase intensity to force change.

With that said, the tag implies that you're looking for exercises to add to a home workout (I read that as exercises with minimal or no equipment). I would look into adding the following.

- Push-up Variations. Different variations can add something to your workout, such as better stability or an increase of upper-body power. You can Google for variations, but [here](http://www.askmen.com/top_10/fitness/top-10-push-up-pro-variations.html) is just one example
- Pull-up Variations. Same logic and reasoning as push-ups
- Squat and Plyometrics exercises

This list would easily change based on multiple factors, including your health and medical history, available equipment, and **goals**. So I recommend understanding those factors first, then creating a routine to meet those goals.